# Packet Tracer - PING from CLI of router to website

Tags: packet-tracer, dns

I am currently sending a PING from a Router2 of the Network shown bellow.

[image]

By using the CLI commands I'm trying to do it in 2 different ways:

1. PING + IP 192.168.1.9. As a result, it succeeds.
2. PING + website www.saludo_uoc.es. The result in this case does not work. The comand window shows "Translating "www.saludo_uoc.es"...domain server (255.255.255.255)"

This failure is expected, but I don't know why this should happen. I guess this is because of a non complete configuration of the ServerDNS? Is this right?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the router (any node actually) requires a working DNS setup to resolve (or translate) names.

Normally, you'd point it to your internal DNS server.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67, And the point I need to choose is the one that has the IP 192.168.1.9 so that it translates to the website URL, right?

Comment: We have no idea which IP addresses you have assigned...

Answer (score 0):

The router has no dns configuration, so it can't translate the name.

You can add:

```
ip domain-lookup
ip name-server x.x.x.x
```